# Why does function getVehicleName prints the global variable vehicleName instead of variable vehicleName inside the Vehicle object?

Tags: javascript

I declared a vehicleName variable in the global scope as well as inside the Vehicle object and the fucntion printVehicleName in the global scope and getVehicleName inside the Vehicle object.
When i call the two functions both prints the vehicleName declared on the global scope. Why does it happen?

```
//declaring a global variable
let vehicleName = "Dodge";

//declaring  a method to print vehicleName
function printVehicleName(){
    console.log(vehicleName);
}

//declaring a object using object literal notation
let Vehicle = {
    vehicleName : "Ferrari",
    getVehicleName : printVehicleName
};

//executing printVehicleName function
printVehicleName();

//executing getVehicleName function
Vehicle.getVehicleName();
```

I expected the getVehicleName function to print "Ferrari" but When i call the two functions both prints the vehicleName declared on the global scope "dodge". Can anyone explain the reasons for this and a way to print "Ferrai"?

Comment: //declaring  a method to print vehicleName
    function printVehicleName(){
        console.log(this.vehicleName);
    } When I change the fucntion like this.It will print undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the reason why you're getting *Dodge*.

1. `printVehicleName()` will always refer to global variable (even if it gets assigned to a method within an object)
2. `Vehicle.getVehicleName()` is the same as `printVehicleName()`

   ```
   //declaring a global variable
   let vehicleName = "Dodge";

   //declaring  a method to print vehicleName
   function printVehicleName(){
       console.log(vehicleName); // vehicleName is global variable
   }

   //declaring a object using object literal notation
   let Vehicle = {
       vehicleName : "Ferrari",
       getVehicleName : printVehicleName // Referring to the global function
   };

   //executing printVehicleName function
   printVehicleName();

   //executing getVehicleName function
   Vehicle.getVehicleName(); // This is == to printVehicleName()
   ```

To have a Vehicle object that prints its own variable, you need to use `this` variable.

In short, you cannot reuse `printVehicleName` for a method within an object since it will no longer work properly if you print `this.vehicleName`.

You need a different method within an object like so.

```
    let Vehicle = {
        vehicleName: "Ferrari",
        getVehicleName: function() { console.log(this.vehicleName); }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create a `method` and use `this` to set the context to the `vehicleName` inside the `Vehicle` object.

An object can refer to its self property before it is created

```js
let vehicleName = "Dodge";

//declaring  a method to print vehicleName
function printVehicleName() {
  console.log(vehicleName);
}

//declaring a object using object literal notation
let Vehicle = {
  vehicleName: "Ferrari",
  getVehicleName: function() {
    return this.vehicleName
  }
};

//executing printVehicleName function
printVehicleName();

//executing getVehicleName function
console.log(Vehicle.getVehicleName());
```

You can resuse `printVehicleName`. This line `printVehicleName(vcName = vehicleName)` will take default `vehicleName` but when calling from the `getVehicleName` you can can pass the context

```js
//declaring a global variable
let vehicleName = "Dodge";

//declaring  a method to print vehicleName
function printVehicleName(vcName = vehicleName) {
  return vcName;
}

//declaring a object using object literal notation
let Vehicle = {
  vehicleName: "Ferrari",
  getVehicleName: function() {
    return printVehicleName(this.vehicleName)
  }
};

//executing printVehicleName function
printVehicleName();

//executing getVehicleName function
console.log(Vehicle.getVehicleName());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function use the keyword this.

```
this.vehicleName
```

Use this to access the object properties.

Answer (score 0):

i changed vehicle declaration part 
first change the value of  vehicleName  then call printVehicleName function

```js
 let vehicleName = "Dodge";

        //declaring  a method to print vehicleName
        function printVehicleName( ) {
     
            console.log(vehicleName);
           
        }
 

        //declaring a object using object literal notation
        let Vehicle = {
            vehicleName:"Ferrari",
            getVehicleName: function () { vehicleName = this.vehicleName; printVehicleName() }
        };
 
  
        //executing printVehicleName function
       
        printVehicleName(vehicleName);
        //executing getVehicleName function
        Vehicle.getVehicleName();
```